# SDL create bordrerless window with rounded corner

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I've used `SDL_CreateWindow` with the flag `SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS` and `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` to make a borderless window. But sdl gives me this *ugly* rectangular window that doesn't fit into MacOS at all. So how can I make a borderless window with rounded corners?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304956/7796092) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show how to use it at all